# Given a single concatenated string, how to split Pandas DataFrame into columns by index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Context

Data is coming in as a text file. There are methods that successfully clean, fill, and organize the data prior to this step, ensuring the data is **always** clean and correct. I cannot change how the data is coming in.

There is not any delimiter, or value that would separate the columns in the concatenated string. Because that, I would like to "split" the data into a DataFrame with columns using a known index from the concatenated string.

I need to **only** act on `self.data[0]` The input data does not have any headers. This is how I'm importing the data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

in_file = "in/cool_data_dude.txt"

class MyClass:
    __init__(self, in_file):
        self.data = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=in_file, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=0, header=None)
```

What I've Tried

I've been able to find documentation and Stack Overflow questions based on splitting DataFrame data in columns, but everything I've found is based around separating **based on delimiters or string values**, not index.

## Input

Example of incoming file:

```
ABCTTY3948573774777300000000000100000001000000100000001000003847774111 01AP38888
ABCTTY9991112000200000000000000100000001000000100000001000003337187298 01AP38889
DEFTTY1102938488888300000450000045000004500000450000045000004500000000 03JU40000
```

## Expected Output

The indexes of where the splices should occur, will *always* be true and remain the same. Col1 is always [0] to [2], Col2 is always [3] to [6], etc.

Expected DataFrame output would be (these numbers are incorrect and do not line up with the above input):

```
0 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 ...
1 ABC DEF 123 456 789 012 345 678 ...
2 ABC DEF 135 135 135 000 000 000 ...
...
```

---

Do not stress about counting correct index values based on the example given. If I know what the methods and split looks like, I can copy it with the correct indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `pd.Series.str.slice`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html

You would apply it as `self.data['col1'] = self.data.str.slice(start=0,stop=2)`

Comment: This is exactly the track I want to be on! It prints successful, but it throws a UserWarning when using it with my code. `self.data[0].str.slice(start=0, stop=2)`  UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access

Comment: in that case maybe try: `self.data['col1']` on the left hand side?

Comment: what I tend to do is use local variables to do all the processing on the dataframe and only in the final step do I assign it to the class as a member. That keeps unwanted scenarios from happening (modifying a class member in place)